# remove side parts of a button to open dialog jquery UI

Tags: jquery, user-interface, button, dialog

I have a button to open a jquery UI dialog, and there are 2 bits on the side of the button. how do I remove these? in which file do I remove them?  thanks.

```
<a href="#" id="dialog-link" class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"><button class='button'>Delete all</button></a>
    <div id="dialog" title="Are you sure?">Are you sure you want to delete?</div>
```

jquery

```
$( ".button" ).button();
$( "#dialog" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
width: 400,
buttons: [
    {
        text: "Delete all",
        click: function() {
            goToPage();
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    },
    {
        text: "Cancel",
        click: function() {
            $( this ).dialog( "close" );
        }
    }
]
});
```

Comment: i suspect you see the `text-decoration:underline;` of your `<a >` which surrounds your button. I think it is not a good idea to put a button into a link. If this is the case you can try to add a css like `text-decoration:none;` to your link. But I by myself would never put a <button> into an <a>.

Comment: so how else would I make it a link to another page? also there already is a `text-decoration: none;` in my css @steven

Comment: You may do it with a link but do you really need a button inside? If you need a button you may want to use the onclick attribute.

Comment: Buttons can't be children of anchors, that's invalid HTML. What's your goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I removed the `class="ui-state-default ui-corner-all"` which removed the parts on the sides.